# http-proxy-middleware not working in react production build i am using proxy middleware for WordPress post API

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, redux

facing cors policy blocked issue at the time of WordPress post API implementation in my react application, to solve this cors issue I have used proxy middleware but this proxy is not working after creating the production build for deployment. http-proxy-middleware working perfectly on localhost (at the time of development)

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
        
            module.exports = function(app) {
                app.use (
                    createProxyMiddleware(
                        "/posts", {
                            target: "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2",
                            changeOrigin: true
                        })
                );
            }
```

Comment: You should explain what the problem is and what you have tried thusfar and why these attempts don't work. Also: edit you code by putting it in code blocks (four spaces before every line).

Comment: facing cors policy blocked issue at the time of WordPress post API implementation in my react application, to solve this cors issue I have used proxy middleware but this proxy is not working after creating the production build for deployment. http-proxy-middleware working perfectly on localhost (at the time of development).

Comment: You should put that in your question by editing it. Also salve the code block problem of your question.